# Саша - (с)ашин

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Все время путаюсь и никак не могу запомнить, с какой буквы пишутся имена собственные, отвечающие на вопрос "чей?" Например, *Саша - сашин*. Подозреваю, что со строчной, но всегда сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Это не совсем имена собственные. Подобные формы относят к разряду притяжательных прилагательных.

> Добрый день!
>
> Пожалуйста, уточните, с заглавной или со строчной буквы пишутся
> притяжательные местоимения? Например, "ольгино пальто" или "Ольгино
> пальто"?
> Спасибо.   dzotty
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
> Вначале уточним терминологию:
> это не местоимения, а прилагательные. Правила таковы: имена
> прилагательные, обозначающие индивидуальную принадлежность, пишутся > с прописной буквы, если они образованы от собственных имён при помощи
> суффикса -ов (-ев) или -ин: Юлина юбка,  Ольгино пальто, Танина
> варежка (в составе фразеологических оборотов такие прилагательные
> пишутся со строчной буквы: ахиллесова пята, сидорова коза). Если же
> соответствующие прилагательные имеют в своём составе суффикс -ск-, они пишутся со строчной буквы: пушкинские стихи, петровские
> преобразования, булгаковский стиль.
>
> gramota.ru