# Строчная или прописная

Tags: прописная

Василиса и василисин муж, или Василиса и Василисин муж?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2921/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD

Answer (score 2):

**Василиса и Василисин муж.**

[Розенталь:](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=16)

> 1. Имена прилагательные, обозначающие индивидуальную принадлежность, если они образованы от имен лиц, кличек животных, названий
>      мифологических существ с помощью суффикса **-ов** (**-ев**) или **-ин-**, **пишутся
>      с прописной буквы**: *Марксов «Капитал», Гегелева «Логика», Вандейкова
>      мадонна, Зевсов гнев, Одиссеевы странствия; Надина кукла, Муркины
>      котята.*
> 2. Имена прилагательные, обозначающие принадлежность и образованные от имен лиц с помощью суффикса **-ск-**, пишутся со строчной буквы: *шекспировские трагедии, далевский словарь, тургеневская усадьба, пришвинская проза.*